# Android studio cursor position on already populated EditText field

Tags: android

Assume the user already populated the TextField with some numbers which are saved in SharedPreferences, if the user re-opens the app & taps on the TextField (which has already the saved values).. how can I set the cursor to be at the end of the string when the user taps on it?
This isn't working:

```
machineOD_input.setSelection(machineOD_input.getText().length());
```

Comment: your question is little bit confusing. When you are taping/selecting edit text where cursor is going with above code? can you provide screenshot.

Comment: At present, if user taps on the numbers in the TextField to edit them, the cursor will appear wherever they tap, i.e. in the middle of the numbers, I want the cursor to appear always at the end (right side) of numbers (string).

Comment: so based on my understanding, there is no scenario where user want to edit the text from middle of the text but always from the end?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: do you have any number limit for that edit text?

Comment: No, I have no limit.